# Unused argument error when creating a Tibble table

Tags: r, tibble

I am working with this data:

```
library("RCurl")
library("plm")
library("tibble")
library("dplyr")
library("car")
library("AER")
library("arm")
library("broom")

x <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dothemathonthatone/maps/master/main_merge1.csv")
maindf <- read.csv(text = x)
```

I am trying to do something very simple:

```
data <- maindf %>% as_tibble() %>% select(reg_schl, year, age_group, fee_monthly, daily_hours, fee_per_inc, deubthrt_total) %>% print()
```

I get the following errror:

```
Error in select(., reg_schl, year, age_group, fee_monthly, daily_hours, : unused arguments (reg_schl, year, age_group, fee_monthly, daily_hours, fee_per_inc, deubthrt_total)
Traceback:

1. maindf %>% as_tibble() %>% select(reg_schl, year, age_group, 
 .     fee_monthly, daily_hours, fee_per_inc, deubthrt_total) %>% 
 .     print()
2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
7. function_list[[i]](value)
```

So I tried the same code using R data:

```
data(Fatalities, package = "AER")
road <- Fatalities %>%
as_tibble() %>%
select(state, year, beertax, fatal, pop) %>%
print()
```

and I got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load `library(ARM)` you should see the following message:

> Loading required package: MASS
>
> Attaching package: ‘MASS’
>
> The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:
>
> ```
> select
> ```

This means that when you call `select` you're using `MASS::select` and not `dplyr::select`

Instead you could be explicit and run:

```r
maindf %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  dplyr::select(reg_schl, year, age_group, fee_monthly, daily_hours, 
                fee_per_inc, deubthrt_total)
```

clashes between `MASS::select` and `dplyr::select` are very common. You can also redefine select to use `dplyr::select` using: `select <- dplyr::select` to save some typing.

Comment: Shouldn't that last sentence use `select <- dplyr::select`?

Comment: @Chris thank you for answering this question. I would've been lost for some time trying to figure it out.